# How to update a column based on the id of another column using matching columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The title is confusing so let me explain, I have three tables I think that I need to work with.

- The first table is called `VendorCertifications` and has `CertID, Cert, VendorID` columns.
- The second table is `Vendors` and has `VendorID` and `Vendor` columns
- The third table is `VendorCert` and has `Cert` and `Company` columns

What I did was insert `VendorCert` into `VendorCertification` and now I have a list of the Certs and the PK `CertID` is now filled in using the identity specification.

What I want to do is to go back and to update the `VendorCertification` table with the `VendorID` from `Vendors`.

I was thinking I can join the `Vendors` `Vendor` column with the `VendorCerts` `Company` column.

And then use a CTE to update the `VendorCertification` `VendorID` column.

This is what I have written:

```
with temptable as (
   select 
       vce.Company, v.Vendor, vce.Certification, V.VendorID
   from 
      VendorCert as VCE
   join 
      Vendors as V on V.Vendor = VCE.Company)
update VendorCertifications
set VendorID = temptable.VendorID
where temptable.Certification = Certification
```

This did not work, I am getting a "could not be bound" error, I have tried to figure out why it is giving me that, but I am having no luck. I am not even sure if I should be doing it this way, I cant think of a way to just do it using a normal update statement because it involves(at least I am thinking it involves) three tables. Any help is appreciated. The list of certifications is around 300 with the vendors list around 40.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
with temptable (Company,Vendor,Certification,VendorID)
as(
select vce.Company,v.Vendor,vce.Certification,V.VendorID
from VendorCert as VCE
join Vendors as V
on V.Vendor=VCE.Company)

update VC 
set VC.VendorID=TT.VendorID
from VendorCertifications VC join temptable TT on VC.Certification=TT.Certification
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already done the intial insert, but if you had not, you might have used the OUTPUT clause to return the ids you just inserted so you could use them in putting info into child tables.  JUSt adding this to give you ideas for doing this sort of task in the future.